# Sort horizontally - each row independently of the other rows

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I would like to sort my data (strings) horizontally but I want to sort each row independently of the other rows.

Is the only way of doing that is to select manually select each row and sort it?

I am not an VBA expert at all, I could do that in c# or java but I hope that this function exist in excel ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the VBA for this, assuming your last row has data in column A:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLoop As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


For lLoop = 1 To lLastRow


Rows(lLoop).Sort key1:=Cells(lLoop, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
                    False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2 _
                    :=xlSortNormal


Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: +1, Nice answer. But if you replace `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp.Row` with `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` you don't need to make the assumption of Column A having contents.