# How can I rearrange the values in two columns in Excel so they are always in a given (ex: alphabetical) order relative to each other?

Tags: excel, formula

Long time lurker, grateful for any help!

Here's my Excel question: Is there a formula (or other method) that would let me take data in two columns and re-arrange it such that the values in each row are always in the same (alphabetical would be fine) order relative to each other?

Here's an example of what my data looks like:

**LOCATION 1        LOCATION 2**

C STREET            Z STREET

C STREET            Z STREET

Z STREET            C STREET

Z STREET            C STREET

And how I'd like those same rows to look instead:

**LOCATION 1        LOCATION 2**

C STREET            Z STREET

C STREET            Z STREET

C STREET            Z STREET

C STREET            Z STREET

I hope this hasn't already been answered somewhere else. Thank you!

Comment: You can apply a sort horizontally instead of vertically. There's a checkbox for it in the sort dialog.

Comment: Follow Doug's suggestion. Tested and worked for me.

Comment: I tried this just now and it doesn't seem to work for more than one row at a time. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think the VBA listed here may be (or be close to) what I'm after:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078043/sort-horizontally-each-row-independently-of-the-other-rows

But unfortunately, I'm not familiar yet with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code?

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLoop As Long
lLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For lLoop = 1 To lLastRow

Rows(lLoop).Sort key1:=Cells(lLoop, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
                    False, Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2 _
                    :=xlSortNormal

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```